# Prove relation is a function, one-to-one and onto. Equivalence class.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ be a nonempty set, and let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $A$. For all $a ∈ A$, let $[a]$ be the equivalence class of a on $R$.
Let $r = \{(a,[a]) ∶ a ∈ A\}$.

Questions:

1. Relation $r$ is a function. True or false? Prove.
2. Relation $r$ is one-to-one. True or false? Prove.
3. Relation $r$ is onto. True or false? Prove.

Can anyone help? Thankyou.

Comment: When you ask about $r$ being a function... you have not specified what the domain and codomain of $r$ should be considered to be.  The answers will depend on that.

Comment: Relation $r$ is a function *from $A$ to $R/A$*?  Yes and further it will be onto.  Relation $r$ is a function *from $A\sqcup \{1\}$ to $R/A$* (*where here $\sqcup$ means disjoint union implying "$1$" is not considered to be an element of $A$*)?  No since $1$ does not map to anything.  Relation $r$ is a function *from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$*?  Yes, though it will not be onto since nothing maps to $\emptyset$.  Do recall that when you talk about functions you must specify what the functions domain is and codomain is... where it goes from and where it goes to.  It is underspecified without that.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thankyou for the quick reply. I was also thinking about what you wrote. The question does not specify any additional information. I suppose it's a function from A to R/A with domain and codomain A. Does it make sense?

Comment: excuse my intrusion but I can asure that $a\mapsto [a]$ is a well define function with domain $A$ and codomain $R/A$, a subset of the power set of $A$ and  which also could be called $A/R$.

Comment: Thanks @janmarqz

Comment: @janmarqz that was not even remotely my point.  The question was not "*does there exist a choice of domain and codomain such that $r$ is a function*"... if it were that then the question would be answerable and one such answer would be as you say.  The question was verbatim "*Relation $r$ is a function: True or False?*" to which the most correct response is as alluded to before that the question is flawed and underspecified... the answer being "*it depends on what the domain and codomain are*"

Comment: I get rather frustrated with incredibly poor wording in questions like these... questions like "*What is the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$*" which is underspecified and unanswerable... when in reality it should have been "*What is the maximal subset of $\Bbb R$ which could act as a domain for a function defined as $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ with codomain $\Bbb R$.*"  The domain and codomain of a function are critical pieces of information that should not be skipped unless it is perfectly clear from context what they should be.  Here, as we are practicing dealing with abstract definitions, it isn't.

Comment: @JMoravitz, bringing $A\sqcup\{1\}$ adds more noise beyond your criticism

Comment: @janmarqz consider $A=\{7\}$.  Consider the identity equivalence relation over $A$, namely $\{(7,7)\}$.  Consider the relation as described in the problem of $\{(7,\{7\})\}$.  Is this a function $\color{red}{\text{from}~\Bbb N \text{ to }\Bbb R}$?  No... of course not.

Comment: more and more noise

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is a function $a\mapsto [a]$ with $A\to A/R$, where $A/R$ is the set of equivalence classes also called the quotient set.

It is onto because each equivalence class has pre-image, for if $X\in A/R$ then $X$ is a class, say $X=[b]$ for some $b\in A$, then
$b\mapsto [b]=X$.

Comment: as a light reference, you can contrast with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class#Notation_and_formal_definition see the 2nd paragraph there. The map is called **canonical surjection** there itself.

Comment: Thanks @janmarqz

Comment: Do you think that's sufficient for a proof?

Comment: Is it the case that r is one-to-one only iff R = iA, the identity?

Comment: @Josh the answer to your last question is yes, precisely in that case. By the way, you might check the article [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (for now and future reference).

Comment: @amWhy I did choose to do so 'cuz someone was misleading Josh, and don't waste your thousands of points you won.

Comment: Understood, @janmarqz. For that, I am grateful.  But I did not win anything.  I don't play games on this site.  There are too many invested in gaming this site.

Comment: @amWhy: once I cleared my position please undo your *"against me"* actions, if you dare

Comment: Sorry but there is no action I took, and hence no action I can undo, unless you want me to remove my first comment here.  Please do not jump to conclusions.  There, comment removed.  I am done here.

Comment: thanx you already did

Comment: If we were to have made the change to the problem to have it ask "*Is $r$ a function from $A$ to $A/R$?  Prove it*" then this answer is still incomplete.  It only asserts that $r$ is a function but does not successfully prove the claim.  It is required still to prove that the function is everywhere defined and welldefined, that each $a\in A$ has one and only one equivalence class.

Comment: a few hours ago amWhy was complaining that at MSE we do not give the service for solving homework and now you come here and downvote 'cuz I didn't do the whole task of explaining everything... that's pretty... you are bullying me.